# Collections Not Found Error : Apache Solr

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-ec2, solr, apache-zookeeper

I have set up a multinode zookeeper and Apache Solr 8.1 cluster on AWS. I followed all the instructions that were there on the official site and was successful in indexing data and querying from it. But I am getting this weird exception in my log files/Admin UI.[image: error_image]

Any idea how can I resolve this exception as this will be the production cluster.

**UPDATE**

Below is the complete error log

> 2020-02-11 23:57:03.910 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-13-thread-2-processing-n:solr-node-1:8983_solr) [c:db   x:db] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : db
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : db
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:1938) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1810) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1749) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:749) ~[?:?]
>           at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
>   2020-02-11 23:57:03.910 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-13-thread-3-processing-n:solr-node-1:8983_solr) [c:mail   x:mail] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : mail
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : mail
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:1938) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1810) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1749) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:749) ~[?:?]
>           at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
>   2020-02-11 23:57:03.911 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-13-thread-1-processing-n:solr-node-1:8983_solr) [c:atom   x:atom] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : atom
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : atom
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:1938) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1810) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1749) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:749) ~[?:?]
>           at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
>   2020-02-11 23:57:03.911 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-13-thread-2-processing-n:solr-node-1:8983_solr) [c:solr   x:solr] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : solr
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : solr
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:1938) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1810) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1749) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:749) ~[?:?]
>           at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
>   2020-02-11 23:57:03.912 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-13-thread-3-processing-n:solr-node-1:8983_solr) [c:tika   x:tika] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : tika
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : tika
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:1938) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1810) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1749) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:749) ~[?:?]
>           at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
>   2020-02-11 23:57:03.926 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-2-thread-1-processing-n:solr-node-1:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [atom]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1259)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [atom]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1259) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:749) ~[?:?]
>           at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1780) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           ... 7 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : atom
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:1938) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1810) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1749) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           ... 7 more
>   2020-02-11 23:57:03.927 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-2-thread-1-processing-n:solr-node-1:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [db]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1259)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [db]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1259) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:749) ~[?:?]
>           at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1780) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           ... 7 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : db
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:1938) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1810) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1749) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           ... 7 more
>   2020-02-11 23:57:03.927 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-2-thread-1-processing-n:solr-node-1:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [mail]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1259)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [mail]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1259) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:749) ~[?:?]
>           at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1780) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           ... 7 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : mail
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:1938) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1810) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1749) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           ... 7 more
>   2020-02-11 23:57:03.927 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-2-thread-1-processing-n:solr-node-1:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [solr]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1259)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [solr]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1259) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:749) ~[?:?]
>           at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1780) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           ... 7 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : solr
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:1938) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1810) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1749) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           ... 7 more
>   2020-02-11 23:57:03.927 ERROR (coreContainerWorkExecutor-2-thread-1-processing-n:solr-node-1:8983_solr) [   ] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error waiting for SolrCore to be loaded on startup => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [tika]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1259)
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core [tika]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1259) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.lambda$load$13(CoreContainer.java:749) ~[?:?]
>           at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedCallable.call(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:202) ~[metrics-core-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:209) ~[?:?]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1780) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           ... 7 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : tika
>           at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:118) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.repairCoreProperty(CoreContainer.java:1938) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.checkStateInZk(ZkController.java:1810) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkController.preRegister(ZkController.java:1749) ~[?:?]
>           at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.createFromDescriptor(CoreContainer.java:1231) ~[?:?]
>           ... 7 more

I appreciate the help!

Comment: you need to provide more info/logs.

Comment: I have added detailed error log!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed same exception when upgraded to 8.11.1 version. A simple restart resolved the problem for me.

```
./opt/solr-8.11.1/bin/solr stop -all
./opt/solr-8.11.1/bin/solr start -cloud  -p 8983
```

Errors from my log:

```
2022-01-24 21:55:12.472 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-25-thread-2-processing-n:10.1.36.19:8983_solr) [c:atom   x:atom] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : atom
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123)
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : atom

2022-01-24 21:55:12.497 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-25-thread-2-processing-n:10.1.36.19:8983_solr) [c:db   x:db] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : db
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123)
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : db

2022-01-24 21:55:12.497 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-25-thread-2-processing-n:10.1.36.19:8983_solr) [c:mail   x:mail] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : mail
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123)
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : mail

2022-01-24 21:55:12.497 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-25-thread-2-processing-n:10.1.36.19:8983_solr) [c:solr   x:solr] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : solr
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123)
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : solr

2022-01-24 21:55:12.497 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-25-thread-2-processing-n:10.1.36.19:8983_solr) [c:tika   x:tika] o.a.s.c.ZkController  => org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : tika
    at org.apache.solr.common.cloud.ClusterState.getCollection(ClusterState.java:123)
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not find collection : tika
```